# Two submodule direct summands are isomorphic iff coresponding idempotent projections are conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I couldn't show the underlined part. Can anyone explain it further?

$End_{\mathcal{O}}(M)$ is a G-algebra where $$g \cdot \psi = (x \mapsto g \psi(g^{-1}x))$$ and hence we have $$End_{\mathcal{O}}(M)^H = End_{\mathcal{OH}}(M)$$
[image]

Source (full book): [G-algebras and modular representation theory (Jacques Thévenaz)](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/130468/files/Full-book.pdf)

Comment: Commenting because I don't have time really to get into the context your link provides. This sounds like the sort of thing that should be treated in any text outlining the theory of idempotents. What I have in mind is Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings* Section 21. It is probably also available in Anderson and Fullers *Rings and categories of modules* but probably spread out in the book a little more. (I'd consult the index.)